# Writing a website with VB.NET back-end, no ASP.NET

Tags: sql-server, vb.net, iis

I've been asked to make a website with VB.NET server-side code, and I cannot use ASP.NET or any client-side scripting. The pages need to interact with a Microsoft SQL Server database hosted on a Windows 2003 server (which has IIS and the .NET framework installed). I've been googling for examples, but all the ones I find seem to be about ASP.

I have some basic PHP experience, and can program in VB.NET, but I've never had to do anything like this before. Can anyone give me a reference or basic example that I could play with that will help me connect an html webpage to the SQL database with VB.NET as my server-side code, without using ASP.NET?

Edit and clarification: I know ASP.NET is server-side - what I have been specifically banned from using is any tag starting `<asp:` or containing `runat=server`. If there are other features of ASP.NET that I can/need to use, then that's fine.

Comment: ASP.NET _is_ how you make a website with VB.NET.

Comment: More specifically, I've been told I can't use any tags starting "<asp:" or containing "runat=server"

Comment: Question has been edited as per my response above, hope that makes things clearer!

Comment: You might not use asp.net specific tangs, but you might be allowed to use html tags. So still you may create a form and use submit button. On form-post you will get all the field value in Request["KeyName"] collection.

Comment: @DarshanJoshi I'm allowed html tags, so yes, that should help

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> More specifically, I've been told I can't use any tags starting "<asp:" or containing "runat=server"

You can at least use IIS, and the .Net tools within IIS, right? You're not completely re-implementing a web server?

Just make a handler (*.ashx), and use `Response.Write()` ,`<%=`, and `<%:` for everything.

You should also look into whether you can use ASP.Net MVC (it doesn't need server controls at all). Otherwise you're essentially back in the dark days of classic asp.

Comment: ASHX = ASP.net web handler, surely?

Comment: @podiluska yes, but read his edits. That much is likely allowed.

Comment: This sounds like what I'm looking for - I'll see if I can get something simple to work

Comment: This looks like it's working - I have an .ashx file that gets the necessary information from my SQL database and outputs the necessary html. However, I have read my specification a little more closely, and it says I need to hand in a single .aspx file to add/amend/delete records. I can't work out how to translate what I have into something that works in an .aspx file - it seems to act like an html page, and does not recognise class declarations. Any help would be appreciated.

Answer (score 1):

ASP.NET is not client side.

ASP.NET is a web development framework which uses a server side language like C#/ Vb.NET. So what you are going to create is going to be an ASP.NET app with VB.NET as your codebehind language.

If you still do not want to use ASP.NET webforms framework to create a website but still like to use Vb.NET as the language, you may think about creating a WCF Service using VB.NET and Let your client non-asp.net web app consume it.

**EDIT:** After seeing your comment

> I have been specifically banned from using is any tag starting

Consider **ASP.NET MVC.** There is no Server controls like what you have in webforms which has `runat=server`. You will be writing **PURE HTML** code and bind with some data as needed.

Answer (score 0):

Well I suppose you could write a web server in VB.net that doesn't use ASP.net, but why?

Given you haven't had a specific restriction against using MVC, I'd look into that.

Answer (score 0):

You don't necessarily have to use  controls to make the website with ASP.NET.   Use plain HTML and have your server side code just output text.  Something like this:

```
<table>
<%= tableRow.toString() %>
</table>
```

You'll use a lot of string builders but it should accomplish what you're looking for.

MVC might be another alternative if you can persuade them that it's not actually doing any client side code.  You're separating the HTML View (and any javascript if they're letting you use that) from the business logic and database logic.

Hope that helps some.